# Где первоисточник списка мнемоник команд для процессоров amd64 в GNU Assembly?

Tags: ассемблер, x86-64

[Документация](https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html)
В руководстве для as не нашёл список opcodes для amd64. Где нужно смотреть полный перечень команд для этого типа процессоров, которые можно использовать в синтаксисе GAS, чтобы это был актуальный первоисточник?

Comment: Похоже, вам гугл отключили за неуплату. [Вот первоисточник от самой АМД](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/24594.pdf) на 600 с гаком страниц.

Comment: Спасибо. Их все можно использовать в  GAS?

Comment: И ещё такой вопрос. Как я могу для процессора Intel 64 bit использовать его родной набор инструкций при написании программ в gas? И есть ли список пересечения команд Intel и amd?